# SpicIE - How to get the real address in the address bar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, internet-explorer, plugins, browser

I'm trying to write a small addon for Internet Explorer using SpicIE.
I understood how to respond to events using code like:

```
this.OnDocumentComplete += new SpicIE.Common.WebBrowserEvent_DocumentComplete(SamplePlugin_OnDocumentComplete);
this.OnNavigateComplete += new SpicIE.Common.WebBrowserEvent_NavigateComplete2(SamplePlugin_OnNavigateComplete);
this.OnBeforeNavigate += new SpicIE.Common.WebBrowserEvent_BeforeNavigate2(SamplePlugin_OnBeforeNavigate);
```

When the eventhandlers are called, I can see the current URL of the event.
The eventhandlers, however, are called for every webbrowser object event, including iframes. I need to respond only when the url that is in the address bar is changed (where you type the url that you want to navigate to).

How do I find out if the event belongs to the top frame\webbrowser? Is there a way to grab the address-bar url using the *pDisp* object or something else?

Comment: When the page is the top-level page, pDisp will match to the dispatch pointer provided to you when SetSite was called. Keep in mind that writing IE extensions in .NET is not recommended.

Comment: so how do you suggest to write IE extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a reference to *Interop.SHDocVw* I can look at:

```
HostInstance.BrowserRef.LocationURL
```

The eventhandlers are called to many times (because of the iframes) but I can check every time if the new address is different from the old one.

*HostInstance* is set in the plugin constructor like most examples - don't forget to verify that *HostInstance* is not null.